# Как правильно сформировать @FindBy

Tags: java, junit

Я использую [io.qameta.atlas](https://github.com/qameta/atlas), как сформировать @FindBy аннотацию в интерфейсе MainPage?
Я хочу протестировать фильтры checkbox на сайте [мвидео](https://www.mvideo.ru/product-list).
Вот как сделал я:

```
public interface MainPage extends AtlasWebElement{

@Description("Чекбокс {{sel-facet-checkbox}}")
@FindBy(".//span[contains(@class, 'fake-checkbox')and contains(.,'{{sel-facet-checkbox}}')]")
AtlasWebElement getCheckbox(@Param("sel-facet-checkbox") String value);}
```

Интерфейс MVideo:

```
public interface MVidioSite extends WebSite {

@Page(url = "product-list")
MainPage onMainPage();}
```

Класс теста:

```
public class WebSiteTest {

private Atlas atlas;
private WebDriver driver;

@BeforeEach
public void startDriver() {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    atlas = new Atlas(new WebDriverConfiguration(driver, "https://www.mvideo.ru/product-list"));
}
@Test
public void produrtTest() throws AtlasException {
    MVidioSite mVidioSite = onSite();
    MainPage mainPage = mVidioSite.onMainPage();

    mainPage.getCheckbox("Apple IMac").click();
}

private MVidioSite onSite() {
    return atlas.create(driver, MVidioSite.class);
}

@AfterEach
public void stopDriver() {
    driver.quit();
}}
```

При запуске кода получаю:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//span[contains(@class, 'fake-checkbox')and contains(.,'{{sel-facet-checkbox}}')]"}(Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.75)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот проблемное место в Вашем xpath: `contains(.,'{{sel-facet-checkbox}})`. Здесь вы ищете скорее внутренний текст элемента, а должны искать вхождение дополнительного класса в атрибуте `class`.

Испльзуйте такой вариант:

```java
@FindBy(".//span[contains(@class, 'fake-checkbox') and contains(@class, 'sel-facet-checkbox')]")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]